# Copy Latest revision

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wat to make a bat file that will only copy the file with the heighest number. 
File is like

```
xxxx,0.xml
xxxx,1.xml
xxxx,2.xml.
```

I only want to xxxx,2.xml. in this folders are more files like that.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort files by name (exclude directories):

```
dir /b /a-d /on "xxxx,*.xml"
```

get the last of them:

```
for "tokens=*"/f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /on "xxx,*.xml"') do set last=%%i
echo %last%
```